# Can not boot in axioo mybook 11

Tags: system-installation

I have a laptop axioo.Laptop brand with windows 10 operating system already installed, and I want to change to Ubuntu. Then I downloaded Ubuntu 17.10, 64 bit and made it USB bootable with rufus. However when I put the USB into the first one in the bios and I went to install it, the laptop cannot boot and go into the windows operating system.

Comment: Have you tried disabling fast-boot (or quick-boot) in the BIOS?

Comment: No quick boot or fast boot option in my bios.

Comment: Do you have a "select operating system" BIOS option?

Comment: There is no such option in my computer bios. At boot time with fedora, it works but with ubuntu it can not.